# How do I avoid a segmentation fault while inserting nodes into a singly linked list?

Tags: c, data-structures, struct, linked-list, singly-linked-list

The nodes get inserted when I insert them in order on the console
How do I make sure that I take care of all boundary conditions? For example, what if the user enters a position greater than the size of the list? Also, I get a segmentation fault when I try to insert *after* a node but it works just fine *before* a node. Here's a picture to help explain my problem better

Also, I get a segmentation fault when I try to insert *after* a node but it works just fine *before* a node.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

struct Node
{
    int data;
    struct Node *next;
};

struct Node *head = NULL;

struct Node *insert(int x,int pos)
{
    if(head == NULL)
    {
        struct Node *temp = (struct Node*)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
        temp->data = x;
        temp->next = head;
        head = temp;
        return head;
    }
    else
    {
        int len = 0;
        struct Node *temp = head;
        while(temp!=NULL)
        {
            ++len;
            temp = temp->next;
        }

        if(pos == 1)
        {
            struct Node *temp = (struct Node*)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
            temp->data = x;
            temp->next = head;
            head = temp;
            return head;
        }
        else
        {
            struct Node *temp = (struct Node*)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
            temp->data = x;
            temp->next = NULL;
            struct Node *temp1 = head;
            for(int i = 2; i<pos; i++)
            {
                temp1 = temp1->next;
            }
            temp->next = temp1->next;
            temp1->next= temp;
        }

    }

}
void print()
{
    struct Node *temp = head;
    while(temp!=NULL)
    {
        printf("%d ",temp->data);
        temp = temp->next;
    }
    printf("\n");
}
int main()
{
    int n,i,x,pos;
    printf("How many elements?\n");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    for(i = 0; i<n; i++)
    {
        printf("enter the value and the position: \n");
        scanf("%d %d",&x,&pos);
        insert(x,pos);
        print();
    }
    printf("Linked list is: \n");
    print();
}
```

Output 1

```
How many elements?
3
enter the value and the position: 
3 2
List is: 3 
enter the value and the position: 
4 3
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Output 2

```
How many elements?
3
enter the value and the position: 
3 2
List is: 3 
enter the value and the position: 
4 1
List is: 4 3 
enter the value and the position: 
5 3
List is: 4 3 5 
Linked list is: 
4 3 5
```

Comment: Please do not post pictures of text.

Comment: Try to add NULL checks everywhere...

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm. Edited.

Comment: @dan1st I'm not sure where I could add more checks. Isn't checking if the head pointer is NULL or not enough for the insert operation?.  My outputs here seem to be contradicting . I'm able to insert in the 2nd, 1st and 3rd position (in that order) but not in say, the 2nd, 3rd and then 1st. Please explain?

Comment: You should add null checks after every malloc and `pos` could be bigger than the List.

Comment: You are never returning anything in your insert function!

Comment: @cocool97 Edited. I am returning head

Comment: [This](https://pastebin.com/YYyaaeMA) should do the trick

Comment: How `pos` parameter is supposed to work? Why don't you check it in case of empty list? First element is 0 or 1? Why do you manage differently the case in which it's not empty and pos == 1? (In that case you apparently leak memory)

Answer (score 0):

You are making your insert much harder than it needs to be. You simply need to iterate with 2 conditions (1) `pos` times or less, and (2) while the next pointer is not `NULL`. You can greatly simplify the insert by iterating using both the *address of* and a *pointer to* the next node. You maintain the current node using the address and your pointer always points to the next node. When you have iterated `pos` times or your next pointer is `NULL` you insert your node. See [Linus on Understand Pointers](https://grisha.org/blog/2013/04/02/linus-on-understanding-pointers/)

Further, you are not making use of any **return**, from `insert()`, so your function prototype should simply be `void insert (int x, int pos)`. While you should avoid using a global pointer to your list, for your purposes of this limited example, that is fine. Know that your list should normally be declared in the scope it is needed and a pointer (or pointer to pointer) to the beginning of the list should be passed as a parameter to make the list available to any function that operates on it rather than it being global.

Putting the pieces together, your `insert()` function reduces to:

```
void insert (int x, int pos)
{
    struct Node **ppn = &head,                  /* pointer to pointer to node */
                 *pn = head,                    /* pointer to node */
                 *node = malloc (sizeof *node); /* allocate for new node */

    if (!node) {                                /* validate allocation */
        perror ("malloc-node");
        exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    node->data = x;                             /* initialize members values */
    node->next = NULL;

    while (pos-- && pn) {   /* iterate pos times && while pn != NULL */
        ppn = &pn->next;
        pn = pn->next;
    }

    node->next = pn;    /* set next to pointer to node */
    *ppn = node;        /* set node at address to node */
}
```

Adding that to the remainder of your example, your complete example would be:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

struct Node {
    int data;
    struct Node *next;
};

struct Node *head = NULL;

void insert (int x, int pos)
{
    struct Node **ppn = &head,                  /* pointer to pointer to node */
                 *pn = head,                    /* pointer to node */
                 *node = malloc (sizeof *node); /* allocate for new node */

    if (!node) {                                /* validate allocation */
        perror ("malloc-node");
        exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    node->data = x;                             /* initialize members values */
    node->next = NULL;

    while (pos-- && pn) {   /* iterate pos times && while pn != NULL */
        ppn = &pn->next;
        pn = pn->next;
    }

    node->next = pn;    /* set next to pointer to node */
    *ppn = node;        /* set node at address to node */
}

/** print all nodes in list */
void print (void)
{
    if (!head) {
        puts ("list-empty");
        return;
    }
    for (struct Node *n = head; n; n = n->next)
        printf (" %d", n->data);
    putchar ('\n');
}

/** delete all nodes in list */
void del_list (void)
{
    struct Node *n = head;
    while (n) {
        struct Node *victim = n;
        n = n->next;
        free (victim);
    }
}

int main()
{
    int n,i,x,pos;

    printf ("How many elements?\n");
    if (scanf ("%d",&n) != 1) {
        fputs ("error: invalid integer input.\n", stderr);
        return 1;
    }

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        printf ("enter the value and the position: \n");
        if(scanf("%d %d",&x, &pos) == 2) {
            insert (x, pos);
            fputs ("list is: ", stdout);
            print();
        }
    }

    puts ("\nLinked list is:");
    print();
    del_list();    /* free all memory allocated to list */
}
```

(**note:** a `del_list()` function was added to `free()` the memory associated with your list.)

**Example Use/Output**

Continuing with your example where you were SegFaulting, you can now complete your inserts, e.g.:

```
$ ./bin/llatpos
How many elements?
3
enter the value and the position:
3 2
list is:  3
enter the value and the position:
4 3
list is:  3 4
enter the value and the position:
1 0
list is:  1 3 4

Linked list is:
 1 3 4
```

**Memory Use/Error Check**

In any code you write that dynamically allocates memory, you have 2 *responsibilities* regarding any block of memory allocated: (1) *always preserve a pointer to the starting address* for the block of memory so, (2) it can be *freed* when it is no longer needed.

It is imperative that you use a memory error checking program to ensure you do not attempt to access memory or write beyond/outside the bounds of your allocated block, attempt to read or base a conditional jump on an uninitialized value, and finally, to confirm that you free all the memory you have allocated.

For Linux `valgrind` is the normal choice. There are similar memory checkers for every platform. They are all simple to use, just run your program through it.

```
$ valgrind ./bin/llatpos
==16615== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==16615== Copyright (C) 2002-2017, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==16615== Using Valgrind-3.13.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==16615== Command: ./bin/llatpos
==16615==
How many elements?
3
enter the value and the position:
3 2
list is:  3
enter the value and the position:
4 3
list is:  3 4
enter the value and the position:
1 0
list is:  1 3 4

Linked list is:
 1 3 4
==16615==
==16615== HEAP SUMMARY:
==16615==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==16615==   total heap usage: 5 allocs, 5 frees, 2,096 bytes allocated
==16615==
==16615== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==16615==
==16615== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==16615== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

Always confirm that you have freed all memory you have allocated and that there are no memory errors.

Look things over and let me know if you have further questions.

Comment: This was a little more complicated than I'd have liked it to be as I'm a beginner. But I've looked into your answer and found it quite informative.Thanks.

Comment: Yes, it took me a while to make friends with how the address of a pointer in a linked list allows you to change the node at that address while the links from the previous remain unchanged (the `prev->next` still points to the same address, there is just something new stored there...). It all boils down to whether you learn it right to begin with or have to struggle with the concept later. Understanding how the address of a pointer can remain unchanged while the pointer it holds as its value is updated is key to understanding the use of pointers.

Answer (score 0):

For starters indices in C (for example for arrays) start from 0.

So you should also use the value pf the position in the list that starts from 0.

Logically if the given position is greater than or equal to the number of nodes in the list the new value should be appended to the list.

Nowhere in the function `insert` you are using the size of the list. So this code snippet

```
    int len = 0;
    struct Node *temp = head;
    while(temp!=NULL)
    {
        ++len;
        temp = temp->next;
    }
```

does not make sense.

If the position is greater than the size of the list then this code snippet

```
        for(int i = 2; i<pos; i++)
        {
            temp1 = temp1->next;
        }
```

can invoke undefined behavior because inside the loop the variable `temp1` can be set to `NULL`.

Also if the position equal to 2 then the node `head` is not updated.

The function has a non-void return type but returns nothing.

The function `insert` can be written much simpler as it is shown in the demonstrative program.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct Node
{
    int data;
    struct Node *next;
};

struct Node *head = NULL;

int insert( int data, size_t pos )
{
    struct Node *temp = malloc( sizeof( struct Node ) );
    int success = temp != NULL;

    if ( success )
    {
        temp->data = data;

        struct Node **current = &head;
        while ( pos-- != 0 && *current != NULL )
        {
            current = &( *current )->next;
        }

        temp->next = *current;
        *current = temp;
    }

    return success;
}

void print()
{
    for ( const struct Node *current = head; current != NULL; current = current->next )
    {
        printf( "%d -> ", current->data );
    }

    puts( "NULL" );
}

int main(void) 
{
/*  
    insert( 3, 2 );
    printf( "Linked list is: " );
    print();

    insert( 4, 3 );
    printf( "Linked list is: " );
    print();
*/

    insert( 3, 3 );
    printf( "Linked list is: " );
    print();

    insert( 1, 0 );
    printf( "Linked list is: " );
    print();

    insert( 2, 1 );
    printf( "Linked list is: " );
    print();

    insert( 4, 3 );
    printf( "Linked list is: " );
    print();

    insert( 5, 10 );
    printf( "Linked list is: " );
    print();

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
Linked list is: 3 -> NULL
Linked list is: 1 -> 3 -> NULL
Linked list is: 1 -> 2 -> 3 -> NULL
Linked list is: 1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 4 -> NULL
Linked list is: 1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 4 -> 5 -> NULL
```

Comment: thanks a lot. Clear explanation. Solved the problem